# Getting Raw text can't be used out side of a <Text> tag. Not rendering String:"

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Here i got an issue rendering text outside of the string. if i am giveing

```
 { article.category === 'Activity' && article.description &&
                <Text style={[styles.articleTitle, styles.activityTitle]} numberOfLines={allTabFilterSelected ? 1 : 3} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}>"{article.description}"</Text>
                }
                { article.category === 'Activity' && article.title && article.imageURL && !article.description &&
                    !article.link &&
                    (<Text style={[styles.articleTitle, styles.activityTitle]} numberOfLines={allTabFilterSelected ? 1 : 3} ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
                    >{S(article.title).decodeHTMLEntities().s}</Text>)
                }
```

Here what i got the issue : Please see my image:
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue ... 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: `S(article.title)` , what is `S` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this!

```
  {
    article.category === 'Activity' && article.description ?
        <Text 
        style = {[styles.articleTitle, styles.activityTitle]}
        numberOfLines = { allTabFilterSelected ? 1 : 3 }
        ellipsizeMode = {'tail'} > 
        {article.description} 
        < /Text>: null
} 
{
    article.category === 'Activity' && article.title && article.imageURL && !article.description && !article.link ?
         < Text style = {[styles.articleTitle, styles.activityTitle]}
            numberOfLines = {allTabFilterSelected ? 1 : 3}
            ellipsizeMode = {'tail'} >
            { S(article.title).decodeHTMLEntities().s }
        < /Text>
        : null
}
```